# Bootstrap affix menu when content has opacity

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

Having a strange issue with an affixed navbar. I have a div classed as container-fluid below the navbar and any content I put in there scrolls perfectly fine with the navbar in place, until I try to put an opacity on divs within that container.

If I set the opacity, the content overlaps the navbar.

See these two examples for what I'm talking about:

No opacity on the div

http://25years.cwhc-rcsf.ca/example1.php

With opacity on the div

http://25years.cwhc-rcsf.ca/example2.php

The only difference in code between the two containers is as follows:

```
div.box, div.box2 {
    margin:15px 0px 15px 0px;
    padding:25px;
    background-color:#fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border:#fff 1px solid;
}
div.box2 {
    opacity:.85;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats the z-index issue

add the following css style will resolve the issue:

CSS:

```
div#menu {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! That did the trick. I'd tried monkeying with that but I was obviously putting the z-index on the wrong element. Thanks a bunch.